# How to exclude certain folders in a recursive search

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will recursively search through a network path and pull the filenames. However the first 5 folders need to be excluded from the search because, well, it's deprecated and they haven't removed them yet (I don't have access to remove the folders).

What I need to do is exclude some folders called: `- BOOT MEDIA`, `1_Do_not_use`, `1_lync`, and a couple more.

How can I recursively search the directory and exclude the correct folders from the search?

What I have so far:

```
param(
  [string]$gather = "PACKAGE"
)

function say($info){ Write-Host $info }

function searchDir($path = "<removed for security>") 
{ 
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {

        $package = Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container

        if ($package) 
        {
            $item 
            searchDir $item.FullName
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $item
        }
    } 
}
```

Image of the directory:

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p4Rc.png)

Image to display the output given from answer:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppqPj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding deprecated folders that may exist anywhere recursively, PS2.0+:

```
function searchDir($path = "<removed for security>") 
{
    $deprecated = '- BOOT MEDIA', '1_Do_not_use', '1_lync'
    Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach {
        if ($_ -is [IO.FileInfo]) {
            $_
        } elseif ($deprecated -notcontains $_.Name) {
            $_
            searchDir $_.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

And a much much faster .NET4+ version that outputs only the full file names, not objects.
The directories have `\` at the end so that it's easy to discern.

```
function searchDir($path = "<removed for security>") 
{
    $deprecated = '- BOOT MEDIA', '1_Do_not_use', '1_lync', 'default'
    [IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path)
    [IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories($path) | ForEach {
        if ($deprecated -notcontains $_.Name) {
            "$_\"
            searchDir $_
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to enumerate everything with just one Get-ChildItem and filter the deprecated folders from the result afterwards, but since the network access is slow, I'm avoiding unnecessary enumeration in favor of the self-recursive function also used by the OP.

**Important note.**

Now the function is pipeline-friendly so that its result can be piped and processed *immediately*.
Whereas OP's function stopped further execution of a callee until all files were fetched because `foreach` statement accumulates the entire array before enumerating it. With slow network or large directory tree this can take minutes easily.

Comment: This will still display the deprecated folders, it's 100x faster but still displays them

Comment: I'm sorry for that, the deprecated folders are the first 5 in the path.

Comment: Another way to exclude those names from *anywhere* in the path is to use a `Where-Object` clause.  `gci $path | where { $_.Name -notin $deprecated } | foreach { ... }`

Comment: @wOxxOm see added image for a better understanding, perhaps I'm not saying it the correct way.

Comment: @wOxxOm It's a start, it's not excluding the directories and still runs through them, but I think I might be able to figure it out. The reason I was the directories excluded is because it's an image directory (where they reload all the images) and it has every file they need for the image to boot successfully, around 10,000 files. So it's just making it much slower then it needs to be.

Comment: It will still run through the `- BOOT MEDIA` directory:     `Directory:`;` \\Path\to\network\- BOOT MEDIA\CheckPoint 80.42 x64`;


`Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name`;                                                                
`----                -------------     ------ ----`;                                                                
`-a---        08/18/2015   2:29 PM       1833 Chasis.PS1`;                                                          
`-a---        12/15/2015   8:10 AM         95 readme.txt`;

Comment: Look at the picture I just added

Comment: @wOxxOm And to answer your question I'm using `3.0`

Comment: Well, I have no idea then. I've added a PS2-compatible code just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: BTW, there's a much faster method of enumeration for network folders: [How to speed up Powershell Get-Childitem over UNC](//stackoverflow.com/a/7208713)

Comment: @wOxxOm The PS2.0 worked perfectly! Thanks, you are a genius!